# Encoding plus-minus symbol in UTF-8 outputs with additional characters

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I was trying to encode a plus-minus symbol in python 2.7 between two numbers (e.g. 10 ± 8.9).

From looking at the python documentation I found I needed to encode the plus-minus symbol in UTF-8 rather than the standard ASCII.

Here is a short example highlighting the issue I found, taking the Unicode value for plus-minus from Wikipedia

```
plusminus = u'\u00b1'
print(plusminus)             #All seems fine, but this is in ASCII format
±

plusminus.encode('utf-8')    #Two symbols are outputted. This is strange!
'\xc2\xb1'

print(a.encode('utf-8'))     #Yep. two symbols were encoded from one Unicode
Â±

print(u'\xb1')               #Parital solution is to accept latter symbol
±
```

Even though I have solved the issue (sort off) by taking the latter symbol, this seems strange that the encoding would output two symbols. I assume I am doing something wrong here, but I can't find any other examples of this happening.

Here are the questions I have:

**1) What am I doing wrong here?**

**2) Is there a way to encode symbols (e.g. plus-minus) in UTF-8 directly without the additional symobols?**

Comment: UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding.  Unicode code points in the range U+0080 to U+07FF will be encoded in two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of my issue. It was caused by the terminal I was using had **'iso-8859-15'** encoding. Changing the encoding used in python to match the terminal encoding fixed this issue and outputted a **±** correctly.

Comment: Hi! Are you using Osx? I have the same problem, but the encodings seem to be correctly set.